# How to customize Alert Dialog buttons like in Google Photos App

Tags: android, material-design, android-alertdialog, material-components-android, material-components

How do I achieve Alert Dialog Button style like this :

[image: Google Photos App]

Do I have to create a custom "Dialog" or this can be achieved via AlertDialog theming?

Comment: Possible Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android

Comment: @okcomputer_kid Not at all. I asked whether it can be achieved via theming or do I have to create a custom one.

Answer (score 0):

You customize your dialog screen like create normal activity screen but you search different dialog screen try [this](https://github.com/eneskarpuzoglu/android-fast-dialog) library.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this library for beatiful dialog

https://github.com/pedant/sweet-alert-dialog

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [**`MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Dialog.md) using a custom style:

```
  new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(MainActivity.this, 
            R.style.MyThemeOverlay_MaterialComponents_MaterialAlertDialog)
              .setTitle("Keep backup off?")
              .setMessage("Backup is free and unlimited at high quality")
              .setPositiveButton("Turn on", null)
              .setNegativeButton("Keep off", /* listener = */ null)
              .show();
```

Use the `buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle` and `buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle` attributes to change the default color.
In this case you can use a [filled button](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md#filled-elevated-button-default) (`Widget.MaterialComponents.Button`) for the positive button and a [Text Button](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md#text-button) (`Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog`) for the negative button.

```
  <style name="MyThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">

    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/PositiveButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/NegativeButtonStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="PositiveButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
  </style>

  <style name="NegativeButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
  </style>
```

[image]